# Error occurred when generating database file (sdf) from model

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce, visual-studio-2012

I have Installed Visual Studio 2012. I am trying to generate the database from my model (EDMX file). When specifying a SQL Server Express connection string it works fine. But when I attempt to specify SQL Server Compact file to generate to, it gives me following error :

> Could not find the appropriate DbProviderManifest to generate the
>   SSDL.The supplied provider invariant name 'System.Data.SqlServerCe 4.0
>   is not valid'

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the following lines exists into your machine.config file:

```
    <system.data>
        <DbProviderFactories>
  <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"/>
</DbProviderFactories>
    </system.data>
```

Otherwise, try to reinstall SQL Server Compact 4.0 or verify your project target is correct for x86 o x64...

best regards,